# Events dont fire when called too quickly

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, javascript

I have a very simple solidity function that just calls an event:

```
     function sendMessage(int id, string title, string message){
       Message(id, method, parameters);
     }
```

When I call it using web3:

```
communicationChannelInstance.sendMessage(45, 'exampleTitle', '{}');
```

I can see it with an event watch just fine.

The problem comes when I call that functions multiple times inside a loop:

```
      ids.forEach(function(id) {
        communicationChannelInstance.sendMessage.sendTransaction(id, 'exampleTitle', '{}');
      })
```

No matter how many times this loop is called, it only shows the latest event.

This is the watch I'm using:

```
var events = contractInstance.allEvents();
  events.watch(function(error, event){
      if (error) {
        callback(error, null);
      } else {
         var eventRet = event;
        callback(null, eventRet);
      }
  });
```

Why does this happen? How can I fire multiple events really fast and execute all of them?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show us the actual failing code, ie with the watch etc?

Comment: Are you sure all the transactions were executed? Also how many transaction you were working with?

Comment: All the transactions are executed, if I check for all the events I see them all, but if I'm checking for the most recent ones and fire the events without a wait between them I only get the latest event.

Comment: @Ismael This happens with just 2 events in the foreach, And all the transactions where executed, I can see them when I query all the events fired, I just can't see them realtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, it's a problem with Ganache/testRPC and web3, if it's set to mine transactions as soon as they get them instead of using the flag to mine blocks `--blockTime` the event reader gets confused and doesn't pick up the transactions properly.

In short, set a `--blockTime` of 3+ seconds and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the same case, but I had a similar issue.
I used `web3js` with `MetaMask`.
When I used this funcion to log events

`mycontract.MyEvent({fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, log){...});`,

it only shows the latest event;
instead, using

```
mycontract.allEvents({fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, log){
   if (!error){
       if(log.event == "Message"){
            console.log(log.args.id);
            console.log(log.args.method);
            console.log(log.args.parameters);
       }
   }
});
```

it shows all.

Comment: Your system does show all the messages when executed.
What I don't understand is why when I run the system first, followed by the loop -it only reads the latest event thrown, not all of them, however when i run the system after the loop - it does show all events.

Comment: From the documentation https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events `var myEvent = myContractInstance.MyEvent({some: 'args'}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}); var myResults = myEvent.get(function(error, logs){ ... });` will get all existing events, and `myEvent.watch(function(error, result){ ... });` will get you only the recent ones.

Comment: @Ismael I've used both, when I try to get the recent ones, if multiple events are fired really close to one another, the second one you used only shows the latest one, if for example I wait 5 sec between each event fire, it shows all of them.